# Does the SSL certificate on a subdomain need to be from the same issuer if subdomain is hosted on different server?

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, wordpress-rest-api

The main site/domain is on Hosting provider A and uses Let’s Encrypt SSL.

Site 2 is using subdomain and is on Hosting provider B. This host uses Sectigo auto SSL.

We have an API call from main site to subdomain site that appears to be failing from SSL error.

Both sites run just fine with the SSL they have, only the API call fails (from main site to subdomain site).

Do the SSL Certificate need to be from the same provider (I.e Let’s Encrypt)? Or is there a way to have the current config work for the API call?

Modification for clarity:  The error the API call gets is CURL error: SSL error no alternative certificate subject name matches.

Comment: Please always show us the error, ALL the error message

Comment: Sounds more like a cross site issue...

Comment: To answer your question: no. The error you're getting normally happens when certificate and domain do not match, e.g. cert is for `www.example.com` and you use it on `example.com`.

Comment: note that a certificate issued for domain.com is not valid for subdomain.domain.com unless you have a wildcard certificate (not possible for Letsencrypt AFAIK). take care that the certificate name on server B is matching the subdomain name